# Storing JSON array in different lists or arrays

Tags: java, android, json, listview

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "TFrom": "b",
            "TTo": "c"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "TFrom": "b",
            "TTo": "c"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "TFrom": "b",
            "TTo": "c"

       }
    ]
}
```

This is my JSON result, I'm using Android/Java and what I want is to get each object in the `"message"` array separated in an array, because each one  of them should be in a list item.
Which means my `ListView` is going to view the `"message"` content in lists.
It's more like this:

```
list1= [{"ID": 1, "TFrom": "b", "TTo": "c"}] 
list2= [{"ID": 2, "TFrom": "b", "TTo": "c"}]
```

Comment: are you sure you want each  of the "list" to be an array of only one item?

Comment: @christopher_pk maybe I didn't clarify what I need but each list item in the ListView should have one json object containing an ID, TFrom and TTo

Comment: @Nuha: Then What is issue ? create a ArrayList of Arrays

Comment: @Nuha if you are open to use the third party libraries you can use Gson by Google. I am making a working solution for you just give me few minutes

Comment: @Nuha check out my answer . you can give any name to classes but donot change the name of variables because Gson maps the value key to the same name variables. like status : true  will be mapped to boolean status in MessageObject Class.

Answer (score 1):

Message Object Class:

```
public class MessagesObject {
    boolean status;
    List<AMessage> message;

    public List<AMessage> getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(List<AMessage> message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {

        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

AMessage Class:

```
public class AMessage {
    int ID;
    String TFrom;
    String TTo;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getTFrom() {
        return TFrom;
    }

    public void setTFrom(String TFrom) {
        this.TFrom = TFrom;
    }

    public String getTTo() {
        return TTo;
    }

    public void setTTo(String TTo) {
        this.TTo = TTo;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
String json="you json string";
MessagesObject messagesObject = new Gson().fromJson(jsonToParse, MessagesObject.class);
```

Ref Gson :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you can give any name to classes but donot change the name of variables because Gson maps the value key to the same name variables. like status : true will be mapped to boolean status in MessageObject Class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want, but if you really would like to convert an array into list of arrays, ie.

```
[1, 2, 3] => [[1], [2], [3]]
```

You can use this code as a starting point.

```
    List<List<T>> YOUR_LIST_OF_LISTS = message.stream().map((e) -> {
        ArrayList<T> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(e);
        return temp;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Replace T with some datatype you want, in your case probably JSONObject.

Not android specific, just java codes. I'm not sure why you would want to do something like this tho. Comment below if this is not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject heroObject = data.getJSONObject("favorite");
JSONArray jarray=heroObject.getJSONArray("message");
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> array=new ArrayList<>();
                        //now looping through all the elements of the json array 
                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            //getting the json object of the particular index inside the array
                          JSONObject heroObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
HashMap<String,String> inner=new HashMap<String, String>();
inner.put("id", heroObject.getString("ID"));
inner.put("from", heroObject.getString("TFrom"));
inner.put("to", heroObject.getString("TTo"));
                              array.add(inner);

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gson library. check below how to implement in project.

### build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Then create MessageModel.java and MessageBaseModel.java.

### MessageModel.java

```
public class MessageModel {
@SerializedName("ID")
int id;

@SerializedName("TFrom")
String tFrom;

@SerializedName("TTo")
String tTo;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String gettFrom() {
    return tFrom;
}

public void settFrom(String tFrom) {
    this.tFrom = tFrom;
}

public String gettTo() {
    return tTo;
}

public void settTo(String tTo) {
    this.tTo = tTo;
}
}
```

### MessageBaseModel.java

```
public class MessageBaseModel {
@SerializedName("status")
boolean status;

@SerializedName("message")
ArrayList<MessageModel> messageModels = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public ArrayList<MessageModel> getMessageModels() {
    return messageModels;
}

public void setMessageModels(ArrayList<MessageModel> messageModels) {
    this.messageModels = messageModels;
}
}
```

Use below code in your main activity:(note: result is your JSON result)

```
MessageBaseModel messageBaseModel=new Gson().fromJson(result.toString() , MessageBaseModel.class);
ArrayList<MessageModel> messageModels =  MessageBaseModel.getMessageModels();
```

Check below example to get the output:

```
messageModels.get(0) is your first message object

messageModels.get(0).getId()=1

messageModels.get(0).gettFrom()=b

messageModels.get(1).getId()=2

messageModels.get(2).getId()=3
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Nuha please check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        JSONArray messageArray = response.getJSONArray("message");
        for (int i = 0;i<messageArray.length(); i++)
        {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            JSONObject jsonObject = messageArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext())
            {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
                map.put(key,value);
            }
            list.add(map);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```